# What's fastest way to compare image in python with opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-comparison

I have to compare all frames of video with one image, and with the compare_ssim it took a lot of time. What's the fastest way can I use to compare image with a score of how similar images are?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import cv2
from skimage.measure import compare_ssim as ssim
import time

start_time = time.time()

# Load File
opening = cv2.VideoCapture("/content/drive/My Drive/Skipper/DrStone-OP1.webm")
episode = cv2.VideoCapture("/content/drive/My Drive/Skipper/[Erai-raws] Dr. Stone - 06 [720p].mkv")

# Get First
opening.set(1, 0)
off_ret, opening_firstframe = opening.read()
opening_firstframe = cv2.cvtColor(opening_firstframe, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# (H, W) = opening_firstframe.shape

# Iterate over the episode
while episode.isOpened():
    ep_ret, ep_frame = episode.read()
    if ep_ret:
        frames = episode.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)
        #ep_frame = cv2.resize(ep_frame, (W, H))
        ep_frame = cv2.cvtColor(ep_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        sim_index = ssim(opening_firstframe, ep_frame) * 100
        print(str(frames) + " : " + str(sim_index))
    else:
        break
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: How do you want to compare them ? Bit-accurately ? In real time ? Please provide a minimal code

Comment: @ma3oun Code added

Comment: You could start four threads, or processes,, or however many cores your CPU has, and pass the frames, round robin to each thread/process.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the mean squared error(mse) or the peak-signal-to-noise-ratio(psnr) to compare images. They are usually used to measure quality of codecs.